# Bootstrap Datepicker 2.0 To select multiple dates

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using a datepicker from bootstrap 2.0, I want to be able to select multiple dates from the UI.

Is there any way I can do this?

```
<input size="16" type="text" class="form_datetime">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So easy if you are using bootstrap. 
Just use `multidate` to `true`

### Code:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
                multidate: true,
            });
```

Reference  [Here](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#multidate)

good to go.

Comment: it is not working for me. I am using bootstrap 3.any suggestions?

Comment: the question is how to load dates with multidate? i have been strugling for a time now, cant use setDate.

Comment: the question is how to load dates with multidate in datetimepicker

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the selected dates into a variable (static, php or other languages) and use the beforeShowDay to display if the date is selected or not.

```
beforeShowDay: function (date){
                      for (i = 0; i < calendarEvents.length; i++) {
                          if (date.getMonth() == calendarEvents[i][0] - 1
                          && date.getDate() == calendarEvents[i][1]
                          && date.getFullYear() == calendarEvents[i][2]) {
                          //[disable/enable, class for styling appearance, tool tip]
                          return [false,"ui-state-active","Event Name"];
                          }
                       }
                       return [true, ""];//enable all other days
                    }
       });
```

where calendarEvents is an array of dates